# Django: prevent logging permission errors from shell

Tags: django

From the Django shell (manage.py shell), when attempting to import a python module that uses logging I run into permission problems: the log files are owned by the web app user

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path/to/my.log'
```

Is there a way to disable / mock / otherwise work around this issue so I can use the module from the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alternate settings file that loads all of the normal settings and then modifies the location of the log file.

Comment: While this works, I consider it a very clumsy workaround for the fact that Django is so prone to implicitly trying to configure the logging system. Thus: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18243

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with this issue at the moment, and my current plan is to simply check for write access to the log directory in settings.py.

If I don't have it, then I'll write a warning to stderr and skip the configuration of logging handlers rather than failing.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a try-except block: try to write to the log file and if theres an IOException, either write the log somewhere else (/tmp or in the current directory) or just disable logging.

See also: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions